# OpenGL Application crashes on other Computer

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opengl

I developed an OpenGL application in C++ in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 64bit. It complied and worked nice on my local machine. The application uses the libraries GLEW, SFML and GLM which are all linked statically.

Now I wanted to test the application on another machine. So copied the executable from the release compilation (and the folder with the shader files). The window showed up in white but it crashed for an unknown reason a second later. Then I installed Visual Studio 2012 and compiled the source code on the new machine but I got the same disappointing result.

What is the reason for the application to crash on the new machine? What can I try?

By the way, both machines use AMD Phenom II processors and Radeon video cards with the newest stable drivers.

Comment: Maybe the computer doesn't have OpenGL capabilities. Try running another program that uses OpenGL on the computer that crashes, and see if it works. (Eg. Minecraft)

Comment: ´Visual Studio should allow you to debug on crash - you've already built it on the other machine anyway, why not run it under the debugger on that machine?

Comment: Try running the application using the debugger on the second machine to find out where in your code it is crashing.

Comment: Minecraft runs on the second machine. The debugger says that it crashes at the first OpenGL function in the code.

Comment: what is the return value of glewInit()?

Comment: Are you using the GLEW that SFML provides?

Comment: I use the newest version of GLEW and not the one implemented in SFML. The return value of `glewInit()` is 0 and it magically works now, even the precompiled version. Maybe it was just abount a restart after the Visual Studio installation. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you use GLEW. Do you check that GLEW initialization actually succeeds? And even if it does, that all the functions you actually need are there?

If the other machine doesn't support advanced functions you access through GLEW, those function pointers will be null pointers and using them will crash the program.